# How do I set the priority of network connections in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, connection

If a Ubuntu 11.04 machine is connected to WiFi and 3G simultaneously, how do I set the priority to let the applications (browser etc.) to use WiFi first? If that's not available, it  should use the 3G.

Basically, I would like to set the order in which the network connections are used.

Edit: I am looking for an easier approach which would be useful for those who are just comfortable and not experts in Ubuntu/Linux.

Answer (score 87):

I am surprised no one has mentioned the simplest command to do this: `ifmetric`. It can be installed using `sudo apt install ifmetric`. This command can be used to change the metric of any interface. The **interface with lower metric is preferred** for Internet.

To use this, first see the metrics using `route` command:

```
$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.2       0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlan0
```

Here, `eth0` has lower metric, so it will be preferred over `wlan0`. If you want to prefer `wlan0`, then lower its metric:

```
sudo ifmetric wlan0 50
```

Now, the routing table would look like:

```
$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.2       0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
```

Now Linux will be using `wlan0` for Internet. The change will be reflected immediately.

Comment: Great answer. Thx (also for the route -n). I had to reboot after installing ifmetric for the command to change the metric

Comment: How to make this change permanent (I want to not use accidentally my iPhones hotspot)

Comment: @ThorstenNiehues: A quick solution coming to my mind to make it permanent is to add the ifmetric command to your crontab, by doing `crontab -e` and then add the line at the end: `@reboot sudo ifmetric wlan0 50`.

Comment: It works. But i can't access local machines after this (via browser e.g.). Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: @tomasb: interesting doubt. That is expected, however, as changing the interface preference will bring you into the local network of the preferred interface. One straightforward way to access local machines would be to access them using a virtual machine. However, better solutions must exist. Let me think and reply.

Comment: I tried this, but I am looking for a solution which lists the networks by SSID, so it's human-readable, and such that the settings are permanent. I found a better answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/722010/193855)

Comment: Bravo, it works for me.

Answer (score 19):

Setting the [metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_%28networking%29) is how you change priorities. The higher metric is more "expensive" to use, so the OS will use the interfaces with the lowest metric if it needs to route traffic. In case the lower metric interface is shutdown it will use the higher metric interface since it is the only interface which can be used to route traffic towards that particular network/destination.

The metrics are specified in the file [/etc/network/interfaces](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man5/interfaces.5.html), link points to the documentation.

Use any text editor to edit the file, identify the networks, and just change the `metric` parameter and save. Reboot is the simplest way to reset all the values without getting into the geeky details of restarting the network services.

Comment: Harry - Thanks for the response - The network I am interested in eth1 is shown in the "ifconfig", but not in "/etc/network/interfaces". What are shown in "ifconfig" and what in "/etc/network/interfaces"?

Comment: Adding eth0 to "/etc/network/interfaces" is more risky. You could try ifconfig as root to change the metric for the interface (check that it stays there after the boot).

Comment: When I ran 'sudo ifconfig eth1 metric 4' I got the following error 'SIOCSIFMETRIC: Operation not supported'. http://goo.gl/UhXBJ says that 'Additionally, not all systems make use of the metric argument. ..... When configuring a Linux system, you add an explicit route command for each interface." Looks like there is no straight forward approach in Ubuntu like from a UI for a novice user.

Comment: It looks like Linux decides itself on the fastest adapter after a quick speed test on all adapters. Metric is no longer supported on many distributions. You can still try and dictate things via "/etc/network/interfaces", but I don't know how successful you will be. See also [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/216678/ubuntu-network-priority).

Comment: Faster network is nice to have but is costlier :) But, it might be expensive. http://goo.gl/K0O6j is too exhaustive for everyone to use it.

Comment: The simplest solution, which everyone does, is just to turn off the interface you don't want to use, or to limit it to "Use this connection only for resources on its network" (if you also have your printer or whatever on that same router).

Comment: Here is an interesting link that says ifconfig won't do it in these modern versions, and that the route command is the best way.  I am not convinced I know enough to do it:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592612/set-network-interface-metric

Comment: @SDsolar: It says that a route needs to exist for the metrics to be taken into account, which is only logical - no useful priority can assigned without some valid route to assign it to. But it is true that modern OS have started to prefer their own measured metrics above the specified ones, although methods still vary.

Comment: Thank you for that pointer, @harrymc.  It really is a different way to look at it than Windows does.  Windows is interface-centric.  Linux is much more like a Cisco router.  But this machine has such a simple iptable that I can't figure out what to do.  In my Cisco training things were a lot more explicit.  Hmmm...

Answer (score 7):

1. Prioritising interfaces for general traffic is done by manipulating the routing metrics. Each route has associated parameters such as hop-counts and bandwidths. See the "metric" option in the man-page for `route` command.

   ```
   $ route -n
   Kernel IP routing table
   Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref     Use Iface
   0.0.0.0         192.168.1.254   255.255.255.255 U     0      0        0 eth0
   192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     256    0        0 eth0
   ```
2. Prioritising application access to network resources is often addressed by "traffic shaping" - I'd use a web search-engine to see if Ubuntu or the router can do that.

---

Footnote.

On MS Windows, but not on Linux, the `netstat -nr` command outputs the same information as `route print`. Including the routing metrics.

Comment: In the man page for route "Metric The  'distance' to the target (usually counted in hops). It is not used by recent kernels, but may be needed by routing daemons.". I am not sure if on a regular Ubuntu Desktop the Metric parameter will have any effect.

Comment: Can you please give me the specific route command to do this?

Comment: @PraveenSripati - I don't believe you gave a 100 of your hard earned rep for such an answer - technically correct, but does not help you or me. :-( I am looking for a specific command as well.

Comment: Really what an answer?? also netstat -nr does not show the metric. View answer from @shivams

Answer (score 4):

This is all because of route metrics. You want to delete the default route with lowest metric and then reinstate the old route with higher metric. Please follow commands below.

Lets say your routing table looks like this:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.16.87.254    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens38
0.0.0.0         192.168.151.2   0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens33
10.16.86.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     100    0        0 ens38
10.16.87.254    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens38
10.16.88.6      10.16.87.254    255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens38
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens38
192.168.151.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
```

Now delete the default gateway

```
# route delete default gateway
```

Now reinstate the older default gateway (note that metric in this case is higher 102 than current default route 101)

```
# route add default gw 10.16.87.254 metric 102 dev ens38                                                              
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.151.2   0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens33
0.0.0.0         10.16.87.254    0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 ens38
10.16.86.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     100    0        0 ens38
10.16.87.254    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 ens38
10.16.88.6      10.16.87.254    255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 ens38
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens38
192.168.151.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens33
```

Comment: This works. Note for any other novices (I had to read this a couple of times to follow what was happening):  step 1 above removes the  entry for `Gateway`=`10.16.87.254`, which is the `UG` with the lowest `Metric` ,  and step 2 puts it back with a higher `Metric` so it is still available as backup in case the `192.168.151.2` is unavailable.

Comment: I wanted to connect to machines directly on a second network, but still use my usual network for general Internet access at the same time. It was sufficient to just delete the extra gateway, e.g. `route del default gw 192.168.7.1` where the second network was `192.168.7.0/24`.

Answer (score 4):

[Update] As of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (server), [`netplan`](https://netplan.io) is the default wrapper for network management. Configuring Netplan is done through a [YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/current.html) file, by default `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` (more details [here](https://netplan.io/reference#general-structure)).

[Routing](https://netplan.io/reference#routing) metric is defined by the "`metric`" option, which expects a positive integer (`100` is the default value generally). Here's the [example](https://netplan.io/reference#examples) from the reference page:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
      - 10.0.0.10/24
      - 11.0.0.11/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 8.8.8.8
          - 8.8.4.4
      routes:
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 10.0.0.1
        metric: 100
      - to: 0.0.0.0/0
        via: 11.0.0.1
        metric: 100
```

The route with the lowest `metric` (path length) becomes the "preferred" gateway. (Use: `sudo netplan try` to enable changes)

Note that in a roaming environment (multiple connections, going on and off), you might want to set the [`optional`](https://netplan.io/reference#common-properties-for-all-device-types) (boolean) parameter to `true` (default is false):

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    enred:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 100
    engreen:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp4-overrides:
        route-metric: 200
      # this is plugged into a test network that is often
      # down - don't wait for it to come up during boot.
      optional: true
```

Notice the slightly different syntax for route metric in the case of DHCP connections.

You can also use `NetworkManager` as a renderer, which I suppose (haven't tested myself yet) would let you see/edit that part of the configuration also via GUI tools.

> `renderer` (scalar)
>
> Use the given networking backend for this definition. Currently supported are `networkd` and `NetworkManager`. This property can be specified globally in `networks:`, for a device type (in e. g. `ethernets:`) or for a particular device definition. Default is `networkd`.

(The very last 'big' example on the reference page shows such a hybrid use of both renderers).

See also [this question (askubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008571/how-can-i-configure-default-route-metric-with-dhcp-and-netplan).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't really tried it out, but NCD (Network Configuration Daemon - 1) can be used for this purpose. The site claims to make the network configuration easy. The syntax seems to be simple.

#Wait for some network connection. Prefer eth1 by putting it in front of eth0.
list("NET-eth1", "NET-eth0") pnames;

(1) - http://code.google.com/p/badvpn/wiki/NCD

Comment: You're right, my NCD software does this nicely; the example there works as-is. I should note however that the `pnames` list is in fact just an argument to the `multidepend()` statement on the next line - this is the one which implements the priorities. The mechanism behind this is that when `eth1` comes up when `eth0` is already up, it executed `multiprovide("NET-eth1");`, because `NET-eth1` is in front of `NET-eth0`, `multidepend()` will go down and come back up immediately, but exposing variables from the `eth1` process instead of `eth0`.

Comment: I looked at it but couldn't figure it out.  This shouldn't be this hard.

Answer (score 3):

## Year 2022: Run `nm-connection-editor`

Ever since the (network) settings were redesigned in GNOME, some functionality cannot be accessed anymore from the new settings interface. To use the old one, which exposes more options, run `nm-connection-editor`.

[Setting connection priority in `nm-connection-editor`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzOMd.png)

Credits to: https://askubuntu.com/a/1061981

Comment: is there any utility for command line?

Answer (score 0):

Here, when both are connected, and the primary one does not have internet, is not using the second connection.

It is possible to use `ifmetric` but must be auto started.

If wi-fi internet is failing, to set the wi-fi connection without looking for internet, in Ubuntu:
Settings > Wi-Fi > Under "Visible Networks" use the wheel at the connection > IPv4 > Under "Routes" check "Use this connection only for resources on its network".
To test it is right: `route -n` and wi-fi interface (Iface, here is wlp3s0) will have one less rule (the Destination 0.0.0.0 was not added).