# Linux automatically switch to wired if wired and wireless connections available

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, centos-7

I sometimes plug my laptop into a network cable at the office, and would like the OS to use the wired connection since it is much faster (than the already active wireless).  But the OS seems to stay with the wireless connection (I assume because it was enabled first).  Is there a way to force the OS to switch to the wired (and down the wireless interface) automatically?

I'm running CentOS 7.  (I found some answers on this topic but they all related to Windows).  Is there a script/hook somewhere that is activated upon appearance of a wired network connection in Linux?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/331720/how-do-i-set-the-priority-of-network-connections-in-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the priority of network connections in Ubuntu?](http://superuser.com/questions/331720/how-do-i-set-the-priority-of-network-connections-in-ubuntu)

Comment: What network management software are you using in CentOS? NetworkManager usually prioritizes Ethernet by default...

Comment: I use NetworkManager.  But it is not prioritizing automatically.  When I plug in my cable it leaves both connections up (wired + wireless) and continues to use wireless.