# Give more priority to eth0 when multiple network are up

Tags: routing

I have internet connectivity with eth0 and wwan0.
If I remove eth0, I will have internet connectivity with wwan0 but when I re-insert ethernet to my system, my system should have internet connectivity from eth0 not from wwan0.

**EDIT 1**

I have added metric value in /etc/network/interface for eth0 but there is no effect on my route.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
        metric 200
```

Route

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
8.8.8.8         192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
10.5.54.64      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 wwan0
59.144.127.17   192.168.2.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.42.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

Thanks

Comment: There's quite a few threads about this here and there, also there's different ways to solve it. [Have a look here](https://superuser.com/questions/331720/how-do-i-set-the-priority-of-network-connections-in-ubuntu), I'd say setting different metrics on the interfaces is the way to go.

Comment: I tried adding metric to /etc/network/interface but somehow those values doesn't get reflect in my route